# Success or Error XFBML response to Facebook Page Plugin

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, xfbml

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin

I have a very basic piece of code (below) that allows you to type in a box and display the results of the Facebook page plugin trying to fetch a page plugin for a specific URL.

I'm trying to get the response that is rendered by the plugin only there's not an error, but am not sure how to access this information. For example, I could type "abc" into the box, it'll try to pass in "abc" instead of a valid Facebook URL, and the page plugin will give an XFBML response "Error: Not a valid Facebook Page url."

Does anyone know if there's a way to capture a successful returned result from this plugin code?

The end-game is to store the URL in a database for each client of ours, but only if its valid.

```
<cfform action="#SCRIPT_NAME#" method="post">
    <label for="fbUrl">Facebook URL</label>
    <cfinput type="text" name="fbUrl">
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
</cfform>

<cfif isDefined("Form.fbURL")> <!--- If the FB Url is defined in the form --->
    <div class="fb-page" data-href="<cfoutput>#fbUrl#</cfoutput>" 
                     data-tabs="timeline" 
                     data-small-header="false" 
                     data-adapt-container-width="true" 
                     data-hide-cover="false" 
                     data-show-facepile="true">

        <div class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore">
            <blockquote cite="<cfoutput>#fbUrl#</cfoutput>">
                <cfoutput><a href="#fbUrl#"></a></cfoutput>
            </blockquote>
        </div>
    </div>

<!--- if the plugin doesn't return some error,
      save the facebook URL in the clients database --->
</cfif>
```

Comment: _“and the page plugin will give an XFBML response "Error: Not a valid Facebook Page url."”_ – what do you mean by that, where does it give any “response”? AFAIK at most it logs a message to the browser console. So unless you want to overwrite the console object beforehand (not a good idea), you can’t “catch” this. Perhaps you could look up the page name the user entered via API? That would tell you if the page exists (and it publicly reachable, not restricted.)

Comment: It writes the text into the body of the iframe. I've done a workaround to make an http request to page prior to generating the plugin to ensure that it exists, thank you for your help in this matter